# AngularJS change select option ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is simple i know but just bugging me i got the following code

```
<label>Role</label><div>
<select ng-change="save()" ng-model="frm.TypeID">
    <option ng-value="">Select Role</option>
    <option ng-value="1" value="1">Admin</option>
    <option ng-value="3" value="3">User</option>
    <option ng-value="2" value="2">Guest</option>
</select>
```

I get the ng-value from the database but can not update it via the controller so how can i do something like

```
angular.controller('testCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.select=function(){
    $scope.frm.TypeID = 3;
}
}]);
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do, and whats the problem with the actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-options`:

**Template**

```
<select ng-model="frm.TypeID" ng-options="role.id as role.label for role in roles">
    <option ng-value="">Select Role</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Admin'},
    {id: 2, label: 'User'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Guest'}
];

$scope.frm = {
    TypeID: 3
};

// fetch value from database then update value
fetchData().then(function (id) {
    $scope.frm.TypeID = id;
}
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/p0j93mbx/)**